# powershell - re-initiate variable from parameters

Tags: powershell

```
param ([string]$command = "sh script.sh $ID some_text") 
$ID = "111"
$command
```

On the first execution I get output for `$command` - `sh script.sh some`

Without changing `$command` in param I need to output - `sh script.sh 111 some` on the first execution.

Is that possible? Any technique to work on this?

Answer (score 2):

Just set your `command` parameter to use a string placeholder for the format specifier to change later.

```
param($command = "sh script.sh {0} some_text")
$ID = 111
$command -f $ID
```

If you need to update `$command`, just place the `{0}` where you want the substitution to happen.

---

**Examples:**

```
# Function that contains your code
# command is defined as a parameter
# assume something else within the function sets $ID

function Start-MyCommand {
    param([string]$command = "sh script.sh {0} some_text")

    $ID = 111
    $command -f $ID
    $ID = 222
    $command -f $ID
}

# Run the function without a parameter
Start-MyCommand
sh script.sh 111 some_text
sh script.sh 222 some_text

# Run the function with command parameter
Start-MyCommand -Command "sh newscript.sh {0} more_text"
sh newscript.sh 111 more_text
sh newscript.sh 222 more_text
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `$ID` is undefined, the command string will have its default text, but with nothing to expand for this variable of course.

The only other way I can think of is that this variable is also a parameter to the script. Something like this:

```
param ([int]$ID = 111,
       [string]$command = "sh script.sh $ID some_text"
)
```

Result:

> ```
> sh script.sh 111 some_text
> ```

Comment: What if a parameter is passed as ID? Then it will be changed!

Comment: @WasifHasan That's the whole idfea isn't it?

Comment: I don't think, please see the comment of OP under my answer.

Comment: @WasifHasan I don't know what the OP wants in this case, but seeing his question states that he wants a value on _the first execution_,..

Answer (score -1):

It's easy. Just declare the variable $ID at the beginning of function:

```
function function_name {
  $ID = "111"
  param ([string]$command = "sh script.sh $ID some_text") 
  $command 
}
```

Comment: thank you Wasif, but that's the point I use `param` at the begging of the script and `ID` I get later. To get `ID` at the begging not possible in this case.

Comment: This causes a syntax error on invocation, because the `param(...)` block must be at the very start of a function body, save for comments; the same applies to scripts, except that `using` statements may precede the `param(...)` block there (but no other statements such as variable assignments).